# What is the difference between those two SQL command parameter declaration methods?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and I am using Windows forms and C#.

The following 2 SQL queries work fine with no issues but I am concerned that one of them might cause problems later and I do not know which one is safer to use.

I just want to know what is the difference between the two command parameters deceleration and value assigning in both first and second methods:

The first command parameters deceleration method:

```
SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();

SqlDataAdapter Sql_Data_Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

long PhoneNumber = 07429114523;

MyConnection.Open();
MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM List_of_All_Orders WHERE Phone= @PhoneNumber ";
MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

// command parameters declaration and value assigning
MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = PhoneNumber;

Sql_Data_Adapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
Sql_Data_Adapter.Fill(DataTable);

dataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable;            
MyCommand.Parameters.Clear();
MyConnection.Close();
```

The second command parameters declaration method:

```
long PhoneNumber = 07429114523;
MyConnection.Open();
MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM List_of_All_Orders WHERE Phone= @PhoneNumber ";
MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

// command parameters declaration and value assigning
MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.BigInt);
MyCommand.Parameters["@PhoneNumber"].Value = PhoneNumber;

Sql_Data_Adapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
Sql_Data_Adapter.Fill(DataTable);

dataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable;

MyCommand.Parameters.Clear();
MyConnection.Close();
```

Anyone knows which method to choose first or second in terms of command parameters declaration and value assigning and which one is safer.

Please help. Thank you

Comment: They are the same, the latter is just more verbose.  Note that phone numbers are strings, not integers, so you will lose the leading 0.  Save the hassle of calling `.Dispose` later by using a `using () {}` for the connection and command and adapter.

Comment: @Alex K. I use PhoneNumber = Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text); because the phone number wont fit into "int32" . so I have to use "long" . is there other data type apart from "long" to carry 11 digits? thank you

Comment: Yes, a string in C# and a VARCHAR(32) in SQL, you must use a string if you want to keep leading zeros.

Comment: @AlexK. It's possible that the OP is not dealing with phone numbers that will start with a leading 0.

Comment: Well; `long PhoneNumber = 07429114523;`

Answer (score 1):

```
  MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = PhoneNumber;
```

The one-line version is better, because

- Everything is done in a single line,
- No risk of misspelling the parameter name in the second line,

But there's still a lot to go wrong. 
I would make a little function which does it all for you, and prevents common mistakes:

```
   // Returns a new BigInt parameter
   public SqlParameter ParamBigInt(string paramName, long v)
   {
       // Fixup parameter name
       string name = paramName.Trim();

       if (!name.StartsWith("@"))
           name = "@" + name;

       // Make the new parameter
       return new SqlParameter(name, SqlDbType.BigInt)
       {
           Value = p;
       };
   }
```

Then to use it:

```
  MyCommand.Parameters.Add(ParamBigInt("@PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber));
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no problem with any of the two methods above. In fact there is a shorter syntax where you do not need to worry about the datatype.

```
MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber);
```

Imagine you have 20 Parameters you want to Add, you will prefer something that hastens your project completion time

Comment: If you are marking down, at least give the reason of it

Comment: That overload of `Add` has been marked as obsolete.  You probably meant `AddWithValue`, but there are reasons to not use that as well http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/